# Best method for varchar date validation in Sybase (T-SQL)?

Tags: t-sql, validation, datetime, varchar, sap-ase

I have a stored procedure which takes as its parameter a *varchar* which needs to be cast as a *datetime* for later use:

```
SET @the_date = CAST(@date_string AS DATETIME)
```

I'm expecting the date string to be supplied in the format "DD-MON-YYYY", but in an effort to code defensively, if for some reason it can't be cast successfully, I want to default to the system date and continue. In PL/SQL I could use exception handling to achieve this and I could do this fairly easily with regular expressions too, but the limited pattern matching supported out of the box by Sybase doesn't let me do this and I can't rely on third party libraries or extensions. Is there a simple way of doing this in T-SQL?

*NB: using Sybase ASE 12.5.3, there is no ISDATE function*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue.  You might be able to do something like this:

```
SET arithabort arith_overflow off
SET @the_date = CAST(@date_string AS DATETIME)
IF @the_date is NULL
    set @the_date = getdate()
SET arithabort arith_overflow on
```

However, this doesn't work well in a select.  It will work well in a cursor (boo) or in logic before / after a SQL batch.

Comment: I confirm it does not work in a select. I just do not understand what you mean by a "logic before / after a SQL batch"
What is a logic in sybase ?

Answer (score 1):

My goodness, if the question was about Microsoft SQL Server then we'd have been in business!

Sybase, sadly, is a whole 'nother database these days, since about 1997, in fact, give or take a year.

If the input format simply has to be 'DD-MON-YYYY' and no exceptions, then I think a fair amount of validation was be achieved by slicing the input using SUBSTR(), after first doing some simple things, such as checking length.

I thought that recent releases of Sybase (SQL Anywhere 11, for example) have regular expression support, however, although it's been a while since I've had to suffer T-SQL. Some googling leaves me in rather more doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do something like this:

```
SELECT @the_date = CASE @date_string
                      WHEN '[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
                      THEN CONVERT(datetime, @date_string)
                      ELSE GETDATE()
                   END
```

?

Comment: that wouldn't ensure that what you're getting is a valid date though, I could pass 99-AAA-9999 to the function and it would pass this simple check. You can make it more sophisticated with a bigger case statement but when you start thinking about leap years and which months have 30/31 days it gets hard.

Comment: agreed, it's just simple validation, not real IsDate(), if that suits you, you can try to convert the supplied text to datetime, and check, if the convert succeeded by checking @@error variable, but as I said, it's half-solution. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this in the second result](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/12/sql-server-validate-field-for-date-datatype-using-function-isdate/) in Google when searching for "validate date string sql".

```
----Invalid date
SELECT ISDATE('30/2/2007')
RETURNS : 0 (Zero)
----Valid date
SELECT ISDATE('12/12/20007')
RETURNS : 1 (ONE)
----Invalid DataType
SELECT ISDATE('SQL')
RETURNS : 0 (Zero)
```

Comment: IsDate isn't a valid function in Sybase

Comment: How are you going to down vote me for something that you added in after the fact.  And after I answered the question.  The only identifier you had was T-SQL, which is most popularly used in Microsoft SQL Server, which does support ISDATE.  Bad etiquette.

Comment: I thought the purpose of voting down was to indicate an answer that didn't help, helping answers that did help rise to the top, it wasn't meant as a slight

Comment: Well the purpose is to answer the post that was posted.  I did that.  And then you changed it.  Not my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure SQL Server knows the order of Days, Months and Years in your string by executing

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
```

Comment: I'm not so worried about ordering of date parts, more about the validity of the date string itself. i.e. I don't want it to explode when you pass in '32-DEC-2009', I want it to default to the current system date.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `convert` instead of `cast`?

```
select convert( datetime , @date_string )
```